# 一点 or 一点儿 on HSK 1?

Tags: simplified-characters, hsk

MDBG lists 一点儿 as [not an HSK entry](https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E4%B8%80%E7%82%B9%E5%84%BF). I've seen other [lists](http://www.hsk.academy/en/hsk_1) that do say it is an HSK entry.

Is it common for the HSK to include erhua variants instead of non-erhua? My understanding is that erhua variants are most common in Beijing. Should I focus my vocabulary on learning erhua variants?

Comment: cf。 HSK dictionary 汉语水平考试词典：（第８１１页）  **一点儿**  甲（名）［后缀］［义１］表示不确定的、很少的数量或很小的程度（a bit; a little):有～小事，一会   **儿**  就办完｜～也不知道臊｜少吃～，别吃太多｜说慢～，我听不懂。

Comment: English, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official [HSK1 vocabulary list](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/HSK-2012.xls) published by Hanban in September 2012, erhua variants may occur in the test since they are included in the vocabulary list.

So you should focus on both non-erhua and erhua variants of the words.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from south of China,people here hardly use erhua because of the habit,but the northern people always use it .I don't think it's a big problem in use it or not.

Comment: What you said is correct. But the question is whether it matters on HSK.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I feel the HSK committee here is being frankly unreasonable with all the 儿化 variants it lists:

- 一点儿
- 干活儿
- 大伙儿
- 纳闷儿
- 纽扣儿
- 馅儿
- 心眼儿
- 使劲儿
- 墨水儿 (seriously???)
- 大伙儿

are all things that you'd never hear in a news broadcast, while 墨水 etc would be, but are not listed in the HSK vocab.
On the other hand, they list as single-character words things that I'd never hear without 子: 梨子, 桃子 (are the only two I can think of now).